Will a 65 gallon heat pump water heater remedy occasional shortages with my 50 gallon electric?
I'm considering installing one of the Rheem hybrid models at Home Depot (XE80T10H45U1 if we go with 80 gallon, or the 65 gallon version of the same series).
My family of 4 has increasing water consumption as the kids grow up. 50 was just fine until recent years, but once or twice a week, we are having loss of hot water in shower.
We have a small townhouse with the water heater in the basement garage. We are close to San Francisco, CA (a very mild climate).
One extra factor: I have been temporarily running the new dishwasher with cold water (relying on its own heating element), and now I will also add dishwasher as a hot water consumer in the house with these upgrades.
So, should a 65 gallon Rheem hybrid be enough? Add an auxiliary tank? Or not worth it and just go with 80 gallon Rheem hybrid? I am open to broader suggestions.
I'm also wondering whether there is a way to utilize the old tank?

What matters is the size of the tank, as you've noted, and also its ability (speed) to replenish the hot water.  For a given size this can vary a lot.  In traditional tanks that's measured in BTU.  With heat pumps it is usually in "first hour gallons" which is hard to compare to traditional tanks.  Also, a tank's first hour rating may or may not include use of its secondary electric heating (if it has that) and if it does, and if you rely on that for your family's routine needs, you won't be getting the efficiency benefit.

This is way too anecdotal to be an answer but .... in my experience in various different situations with 4 or 5 people, a dishwasher and a washing machine , a cheap 50 gallon tank often runs out, and a good (not cheap) 80 gallon one literally never does.    I do not know how that translates to hybrid ones.  They are all expensive!  You would hope that an 80 gallon tank will easily service a family of four but ... how to be sure?

A dishwasher barely uses any water. Maybe a couple gallons at most. Given the current global environmental crisis, I suggest a consumption audit. My family of 4 has almost never run out with our 40 and 50 gallon heaters in Minnesota, where incoming water temps are down near 40F in winter. Consider lower flow shower heads, reasonable shower length, etc. The planet cannot support ever-expanding luxury.

If your contractor had specced an 80 gallon, and you were arguing in favor of a 65 gallon, what would your argument be?  (other than "I'm the customer").

Does anyone in your family take baths?

To answer your question, without listing the hot water tank(s) specs regarding recovery rate and a reasonably accurate estimation of hot water usage there is no way to know if whatever size tank you want to upsize to will be enough.  There's many online things explaining how to calculate what hot water tank size you need... https://reco-cs.com/guidelines-for-sizing-a-hot-water-heating-system/

Edited the question, considering Rheem hybrid XE80T10H45U1 80 gallon at Home Depot (or 65 gallon version of the same model), 87 gallon first hour: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rheem-Performance-Platinum-80-Gal-Smart-High-Efficiency-Hybrid-Heat-Pump-Water-Heater-with-10-Year-Warranty-XE80T10H45U1/330317276
